# Modifying image height from context menu in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my XAML page I define an image with a context menu:

```
<Image Height="{Binding Image.Height, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxHeight="2000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform"
Source="{Binding Image.ImageData, Converter={StaticResource ImageByteConverter}}"
x:Name="Image1">

<Image.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="200" Click="ImageHeight200_Click" />
    <MenuItem Header="400" Click="ImageHeight400_Click" />
    <MenuItem Header="600" Click="ImageHeight600_Click" />
    <MenuItem Header="800" Click="ImageHeight800_Click" />
    <MenuItem Header="1000" Click="ImageHeight1000_Click" />
</ContextMenu>
</Image.ContextMenu>
</Image>
```

Now I want to add code to resize the image.

When I write something like this

```
private void ImageHeight200_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var img = (Image)e.Source;
    img.Height = 200;
}
```

It accesses the MenuItem but not the image and I get an error message:

> The object of type "System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem" cannot be converted to type "System.Windows.Controls.Image".

**My Question is:**

How can I access the image object?

Comment: Can you post your error message ?

Comment: and also your bindable class values because you cast an Image to your class Image and change the height that looks very confusing

Comment: Probably the reason is that it appears in a StackPanel, so several images can be shown with the same code. Therefore it isn't possible to reference a particular image this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reference the image by name

```
private void ImageHeight200_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image1.Height = 200;
}
```

Comment: That would be the most elegant solution, but it does not work: I get "The name 'Image1' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: That is odd. Is your `ImageHeight200_Click` method in the code-behind of the xaml page that the image exists in?

Answer (score 0):

You could use PlacementTarget property of ContextMenu

```
private void ImageHeight200_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e){
MenuItem mnu = sender as MenuItem;
Image sp = null;
if(mnu!=null)
{
    sp = ((ContextMenu)mnu.Parent).PlacementTarget as Image;
}}
```